# use Aggregate function with multiple table in Access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba

I have Four tables Items,Customer,Invoice_summary,Invoice_details. Here I want to join these four tables and to get Sum(Invoice_details.Item_quntity) and Sum(Invoice_details.Price) for a specific item_code and for a specific date range . Main Columns are as follows:

```
Invoice_summary :Inv_num,Inv_date,Cus_id,Total 
Items           :Item_code,Item_name,Unit_price
Invoice_details :Inv_num,Item_code,Item_qty,Price
Customers       :Cus_id,Cus_name,Route
```

Here is what I currently have.this return more than a row(whole itemsnames) i need only for a specific item code.Could someone explain where I am going wrong.

```
SELECT Invoice_Table.Item_Code, Items.Item_Name, 
       (Select sum(Invoice_Table.Item_Quntity)  from (Invoice_Table INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice_Table.Inv_Num = Invoice.Inv_Num) where ((Invoice_Table.Item_Code=[?]) And Invoice.inv_date Between #3/4/2013# And #6/4/2013#) group BY Invoice_Table.Item_Code) AS Quntity, 
       (Select sum(Invoice_Table.Price)  from (Invoice_Table INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice_Table.Inv_Num = Invoice.Inv_Num) where ((Invoice_Table.Item_Code=[?]) And Invoice.inv_date Between #3/4/2013# And #6/4/2013#) group BY Invoice_Table.Item_Code) AS Price 
FROM Invoice_Table 
INNER JOIN Items ON Invoice_Table.Item_Code = Items.Item_Code 
GROUP BY Invoice_Table.Item_Code, Items.Item_Name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sums you're interested in should be given by this query.

```
select Inv_num, Item_code, 
       sum(Item_qty) item_code_qty, 
       sum(Price) item_code_price
from invoice_details
group by Inv_num, Item_code
```

It looks like the date range should be found in the invoice summary table. It looks like Invoice_summary and Invoice_details should be joinable on Inv_num.

```
select inv_s.Inv_num, inv_s.Inv_date, inv_s.Cus_id, inv_s.Total,
       inv_t.item_code_qty, inv_t.item_code_price
from Invoice_summary inv_s
inner join (select Inv_num, Item_code, 
                   sum(Item_qty) item_code_qty, 
                   sum(Price) item_code_price
            from invoice_details
            group by Inv_num, Item_code
            ) inv_t
        on inv_s.Inv_num = inv_t.Inv_num
where inv_s.Inv_date between ? and ?;
```

And to round that out, join the other two tables on their keys, and add some of their columns to the SELECT clause.

```
select inv_s.Inv_num, inv_s.Inv_date, inv_s.Cus_id, cus.Cus_name, inv_s.Total,
       inv_t.item_code_qty, inv_t.item_code_price,
       items.name
from Invoice_summary inv_s
inner join (select Inv_num, Item_code, 
                   sum(Item_qty) item_code_qty, 
                   sum(Price) item_code_price
            from invoice_details
            group by Inv_num, Item_code
            ) inv_t
        on inv_s.Inv_num = inv_t.Inv_num
inner join items on items.Item_code = inv_t.Item_code
inner join Customers cus on cus.Cus_id = inv_s.Cus_id
where inv_s.Inv_date between ? and ?;
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.but still i cant filter the data with date range.it asking In_num as input. i have upload the sample.will you please explain where I am going wrong?                           <a href="http://sdrv.ms/116eueC">

Comment: "In_num" isn't a column in your tables. My guess is that you made a typo, and you meant "Inv_num".

Comment: ohh.. sorry sir,it is typo.finally i figure out after messing with it couple of hours. i join this table and filter though the date range,route and cus_id.thank you very much  for teach me how to approach to such a problem.(two thumbs up)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Select ID.Item_qty,ID.Price,I.Item_code from Invoice_summary IS 
INNER JOIN Invoice_details ID ON ID.Inv_num=IS.Inv_num
INNER JOIN Customers C ON C.Cus_id=IS.Inv_num
INNER JOIN Items I ON I.Item_code=ID.Item_code
```